# Finding if exponent share is present in dlog instance

Tags: discrete-logarithm

Let $g$ be a group generator of prime order $q$. Suppose we are given two elements $g^y$ and $x_1$. Can we find out if $y=x_1+x_2$ for some $x_2$?

Thanks

Comment: If $y$ is an integer, and $x_1$ is a group element, how does $y - x_1 = x_2$ make sense?  Are you assuming a specific group representation (so you can map between integers and group elements)?  Are, if you compute $y - x_1$ either in the integers or within the group, won't such an $x_2$ always exist?

Comment: As poncho says, your question doesn't make sense as currently written. As such I feel I have to downvote and close-vote, but as soon as you sort it out I'd be very happy to reverse the vote :)

Comment: I recommend using uppercase letters for group elements and lower case letters for scalars. That way you easily see that you're adding a scalar an a group element which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand your question.

Your question is that given generator $g$ of a prime order $q$ group and some element $g^y$ of that group and another element $x_1 \in Z_q$ you want to check if there is such an $x_2$ or find $x_2\in Z_q$ such that $y\equiv x_1+x_2 \pmod q$? I assume that in this setting the discrete logarithm problem is hard, right?

Firstly, for every $y\in Z_q$ you will find a decomposition in $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $y\equiv x_1+x_2 \pmod q$. Your value will just be $x_2\equiv y-x_1 \pmod q$. So, yes this is always true.

Secondly, can we efficiently find such $x_2$? If there would be an efficient way to do so, then given $(q,g,g^y)$, take an arbitrary $x_1 \in Z_q$ which will be an instance to your problem. Since we know there is an $x_2$ in any case, figure out $x_2$ and output $y\equiv x_1 +x_2 \pmod q$, which is a solution to the discrete logarithm problem. So if the discrete logarithm problem is hard, figuring out $x_2$ is hard (as otherwise this algorithm would provide an efficient reduction to the discrete logarithm problem).